# use of pointer with getline() function

Tags: c++

```
char *p;
cout << "Enter the string and press ENTER: ";
cin.getline(p,delimiter);
```

How this code should works,like from compilers point of view.I mean a character pointer should take a character only but when I run this code it takes characters up to delimiter. Here delimiter could be any int. **Ex-2,10,1200**.

It should show compiler error that you have not allocated memory to char pointer but it compiles

Comment: allocate memory first

Comment: You cannot use `std::istream::getline()` with an unallocated buffer. Initialize `p` with a reasonable value.

Comment: A pointer can point either to a single element or to the first in a sequence of elements. It's up to the program to know which.

Comment: _"How this code should works,like from compilers point of view"_ As it is it's undefined behavior. The compiler is allowed to emit any code.

Comment: Also, you want the three parameter version of `getline`. Currently data will be read into the undefined space at `p` up to the end of the line or the numeric value of `delimiter` whichever comes first. The code leaves out the count of characters needed. If possible consider using `std::getline` and a `std::string`.

Comment: **allocate memory first** <- that is what i am asking that i have not allocated  memory still compiler compiles rather than showing error.

Comment: Ah, so your question isn't "how should this code work", your question is "WHY does this code work" - because you believe it should fail at the compiler. I suggest you reword the question - it will be clearer for people following.

Comment: @AnkitMahlawat: your code syntax is *technically* correct, but *semantically* wrong. The compiler can only validate syntax, not semantics. You are calling the version of `getline()` that expects a pointer, and you are passing it a pointer. The compiler is happy. But it doesnt generate extra code to make sure you are allocating memory for the pointer to point at. That is your responsibility.

Comment: that is why I am asking that how getline function works what could be the code inside compiler for getline function

Answer (score 0):

> It should show compiler error that you have not allocated memory to
>   char pointer but it compiles

The compiler cannot generally do that anyway. Consider this adaption to your example:

```
int size;
std::cin >> size;
char *p = new char[size];
cout << "Enter the string and press ENTER: ";
cin.getline(p,delimiter);
```

Here you do allocate memory, but how much is not known until the program runs and the user has entered some number.

If you want to develop in C++, then you have to understand and live with the fact that **undefined behaviour** is a valid, common and risky result of programming errors.

Your assumption that the compiler can or should find all errors is neither correct nor desirable in the world of C++.

Ways to cope with this reality include:

- Being cautious.
- Enabling more compiler warnings.
- Not ignoring compiler warnings.
- Preferring safe standard components like `std::getline` and `std::string`, which have fewer ways of producing undefined behaviour.
- Using `assert` a lot.

Answer (score -3):

```
char *p;

cout << "Enter yes or no ";
cin >> p;
```

This is how you get `char`.

As for your question, think of it this way, if you are using `getLine()`, then you are reading the whole line given up to the delimiter. You did not specify which `char` you want the compiler to read if the white space delimiter is not present in the input.

If you wanted to find a char in your input, you couldve used the find function or `getLine(p,"insert char you are looking for here"` or if you want the first `char`, there is a built in `find_first_of function`.

Comment: Whether using `cin.getline()` or `cin >> p`, you still have to allocate memory for `p` to point at, then `cin` will fill in the memory with data. If you want the STL to allocate the memory for you, use `std::string` with `std::getline()` instead.